# Running a particular test among multiple tests with same name

Tags: maven, unit-testing

I have multiple tests with same name but under different packages

> com.private.db.dao.pf.ent.DAOBaseFuncTest
>   com.private.db.dao.internal.pf.ent.DAOBaseFuncTest
>   com.private.db.dao.core.ent.DAOBaseFuncTest

I wanted to run `com.private.db.dao.pf.ent.DAOBaseFuncTest`. Usually I run a test with this command,

```
mvn -Prun-tests -pl test/func -Dit.test=DAOBaseFuncTest verify
```

But I was surprised to see 3 test suites running one after another. Is it possible to run a particular test suite instead of running all the three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I tried giving the specific test suite and it worked.

`mvn -Prun-tests -pl test/func -Dit.test=com.private.db.dao.pf.ent.DAOBaseFuncTest verify`